# How to match letter combination and it's occurences

Tags: regex, match

Let's say I have this text :

```
antianti
barbary
barberbarber
```

How can I match other occurences of the first 2 letters in each of those 'words', for example `an\an` in the first word and `ba\ba` in the second one ? I was trying to get it with :

```
/(^\w{2})/gm
```

Plus `\n` or `{2}` but to no eval. Any tips what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: No regex, just `str.indexOf(str.slice(0, 2))`?

Comment: He wants to match the characters in forward or reverse order.

Comment: @Barmar: How did got "reverse order"? Both example seem to be just forward.

Comment: What language are you doing this in? I gave an answering using positive lookbehind, but Javascript doesn't support it.

Comment: It's for a general purpose, right now testing it in http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this regex should work out for you:

```
^(\w{2})(?=.*\1)
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/jV7uF3

Comment: This is matching the first two characters of the line if they happen to be repeated, it's not finding the repetitions.

Comment: Probably I misunderstood but this finds **first 2 characters** only when there is a repetition. Is that not correct?

Comment: He says he wants to match the _other_ occurrences of the first two characters.

Comment: E.g. in the first example, it should match characters 5-6.

Comment: But *other occurrences* are also repetitions so no matter what it will still produce same result.

Comment: Suppose you want to use the regular expression with `preg_replace()`. Yours will only replace the first occurrence, not the repetitions.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough with my question, but the first regex is enough for my needs. Additionally I think you can remove `?` after `.`.

Comment: That is great to know. In comments you can see that I  interpreted question correct initially :)

Answer (score 1):

This captures the first two characters of each line and the last occurrence.

```
/^(\w{2})(?:.*)(\1)/gm
```

This captures the first two characters of each line and the next occurrence.

```
/^(\w{2})(?:.*)(\1)/gmU
```

Now this gets ugly, but ... the next two occurrences.

```
/^(\w{2})(?:.*(\1).*(\1)|.*(\1))/gmU
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the first two letters in a lookbehind, and then use back-references to match later occurrences.

```
/^(?<=(\w\w).*)\1/gm
```

Comment: Tried it here : http://regex101.com/r/dC2sQ7 and it appears to be an invalid regex.

Comment: It was invalid because of the quantifier inside the lookbehind, that's not allowed. But it didn't work even when I moved that outside the lookbehind. It looks like backreferences don't work to matches inside the lookbehin

Comment: I also thought it's gonna be way easier :)

Comment: Your regex looks weird. Why are you checking the previous line for `(\w\w).*` (assuming the engine accepts it)?

Comment: I'm not checking the previous line, I'm using that to capture the first two characters of the string.